# What does template mean as a suffix of a class name?

Tags: java, class, design-patterns, template-method-pattern

In many programs, a Class with the suffix Template exists.
For example, `org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate`, etc.

What does template mean as a class name suffix? 
Does it mean [the Template Method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern)?

Do you know the reason?

Have a good day.

Comment: It means the class name ends in the word `Template`; nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: It means whatever the developer wants it to mean. I would assume it's some sort of template, but like I said, it all depends on how the developer that created that class defines template. For all we know, it could be a poorly named class.

Answer (score 1):

No , 'org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate' is not proper example of 'Template Method Pattern'. It is given name due to its similarity with other classes in spring with suffix as template like 'JDBCTemplate' , 'JMSTemplate'. 
These classes Both classes , providing a simplified approach with default behaviors for performing complex tasks.
Although JDBCTemplate option for user to extend methods like insert and update but Resttemplate does not comply with it.